# Scrape Data from Yahoo finance headline

Tags: python, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I did some research across this website to find a way  to resolve my problem, but either the threads where too old ( Yahoo refresh it's page a few years ago), or they were too complicated ( I'm still **new** to scraping).
I would like to search for keyword in the csv file created by this code.

I used this code, but the headlines in Yahoo are kind of tricky to get , let me explain.

```
# import libraries
import urllib2  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import csv  
from datetime import datetime

quote_page = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/' 
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 
name_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'name'})
name = name_box.text.strip() 
print name


with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:  
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerow([name, ])
```

As you may see in this picture, the headline are between these :
!-- react-text: 3388 -->
!-- /react-text -->
But I don't know how to transform my code to be able to read these.

The solution might be pretty simple but I tried many things and nothing seems to work.

[image: Yahoo headlines]

I hope you will be able to help me or find another way to find keyword in these headlines.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried selecting innerText for the anchor tag just above the StretchedBox?

Answer (score 0):

I used `requests` instead of `urllib2`. From what I hear, it's what more people use.

As for the headline:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/m/8bb0b8f6-9b97-32df-8f56-31690cd85cea/long-lines-are-killing.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.content, 'lxml')
search = soup.find_all('h1', {'class':'Lh(36px) Fz(25px)--sm Fz(32px) Mb(17px)--sm Mb(20px) Mb(30px)--lg Ff($ff-primary) Lts($lspacing-md) Fw($fweight) Fsm($fsmoothing) Fsmw($fsmoothing) Fsmm($fsmoothing) Wow(bw)'})
print(search[0].text) # prints Long Lines Are Killing Starbucks, So Here's Its Bold New Solution to the Major Problem
```